# sql I don't want to lose null values when I'm using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, group-by

I'm trying to find which merch made visit a poi which is out of his route. In order to do this I need to find null values from vp.poiid however when I make group by I lost null values on that column.

```
.
.
.
(SELECT
    vp.routedate AS Date,
    me.MerchName,
    me.id AS Merchid,
    ov.poiid AS Done,
    vp.poiid AS Planned,
    CASE WHEN ov.poiid IS NULL THEN COUNT(ov.poiid) END AS notDone,
    CASE WHEN vp.poiid IS NULL THEN COUNT(vp.poiid) END AS outOfRoute

FROM atb_visitplan vp

FULL JOIN OutVisitData ov ON (vp.poiid = ov.poiid 
AND ov.commitdate = vp.routedate 
AND vp.merchid = ov.merchid)

INNER JOIN atb_merchs me ON (vp.merchid = me.id)

WHERE me.id = 1  
GROUP BY 
    vp.routedate,
    me.MerchAd,
    me.id,
    ov.poiid,
    vp.poiid
) a
.
.
.
```

when I run this subquery I get this view:

```
     date                 name      id  done   planned  notdone  outofroute
2013-11-06 00:00:00.000 Seven Kavak 1   30      30      0       NULL
2013-11-06 00:00:00.000 Seven Kavak 1   34      34      0       NULL
2013-11-06 00:00:00.000 Seven Kavak 1   48      48      0       NULL
2013-11-06 00:00:00.000 Seven Kavak 1   54      54      0       NULL
2013-11-06 00:00:00.000 Seven Kavak 1   NULL    1235    1235    NULL
2013-11-06 00:00:00.000 Seven Kavak 1   NULL    1236    1236    NULL
2013-11-07 00:00:00.000 Seven Kavak 1   30      30      0       NULL
2013-11-07 00:00:00.000 Seven Kavak 1   49      49      0       NULL
```

As you see in this result outOfRoute values all NULL (but it is actually not). Is there any way to see the actual results in this table? And I need to group these columns, this is a subquery and I count the final results. Planned column have null values actually but I cannot see them also.

PS: I'm using sql server

Answer (score 0):

I think I misread the first time.  You want a count of the records which have nulls for those, right?

```
COUNT(SELECT * FROM ov WHERE ov.poiid IS NULL) AS notDone,
COUNT(SELECT * FROM vp WHERE vp.poiid IS NULL) AS outOfRoute
```

Your current statements say, "Display a count of these records when the grouped field is null," which it looks is never.

You'll need to redefine the joins within those selects; I went for brevity for the moment.

(Rewritten with, I hope, better answer.)

Comment: Nope it cannot find any null values I make something like 
GROUPING(vp.poiid) WITH ROLLUP but this time it brings meaningless records

Comment: You're right actually I have to find out another way for not to lose null values.

Answer (score 0):

your `CASE WHEN vp.poiid IS NULL THEN COUNT(vp.poiid) END AS outOfRoute` statement will count only when vp.poiid  is null and you dont have else part. If i check the result all your `vp.poiid AS Planned` column is having values so obviously you will get null values in `outOfRoute column`.

Comment: I don't need else part, I try to count null values but the problem is null values are lost when I make group by.

Comment: I didnt get you!! are you trying to say that null values are lost in vp.poiid column while you group

Comment: yep that's what I say